# Optimizing weak symbols lookup

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, llvm, binutils

If you ever tried to use the *nm* utility on any C++ program you have probably noticed that many symbols are identified as 'V' or 'W'. Both are different kind of *weak* symbols.

Now, having tons of weak symbols in an executable is bad, since at runtime the dynamic linker will try to resolve them all. I was thinking that it could be possible to save a lot of time by enforcing a simple convention when linking executable files:

- Whenever a weak symbol would be created in the executable, if such symbol has a default value, promote it to a regular symbol.

This hack seems safe to me, since:

- If any library defines a weak symbol with the same name, it will be overridden by the promoted one and this is fine since for weak symbols we are free to choose any definition
- If no library actually defines such symbol... nothing special happens
- If the libraries defines weak symbols which are not defined in the executable everything works as usual.

Before I try to discuss this with binutils developers, is there a huge mistake I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that would stop what you describe from working.

I do however wonder if this is worth doing at all. And I'm pretty sure that's what your "binutils developers" would wonder as well.

So I suggest you look at a few things: How often, in the typical case, is the same symbol defined in the executable, and in a dynamic library?

Since there will most likely still be a large number of weak symbols left that are not defined in the executable, how much time do you actually save?

Some examples of existing programs that are improved or at least an answer to "For application X, this much time is spent on average looking up a weak symbol and this is the potential gain?"

That's what I'd be looking for as a binutils developer [I'm not one of those, but if I were].

Comment: Actually, my point is that the typical large scale C++ application (I started my investigation by studying the performance of the clang compiler), a large number of weak symbols comes from the executable itself. The advantage of promoting the symbols from the executable is that they will not be looked up, but they will still be capable of overriding eventually weak symbols in linked libraries, as this is required by the C++ ODR rule.

Comment: Yes, and my point is that you need to show that it's worth doing - the number of references to weak symbols and the saving in time needs to be big enough that it makes a noticeable difference. I haven't looked at it, but I suspect that the "lookup" part is not that huge a part of the loading process that it makes a huge saving - but I haven't looked into the details, I'm just suggesting that if you want to do this, you'd be prepared to explain what the saving is in a real [preferrably popular] application - perhaps FireFox or Chrome?